# Unity 5 - Input Field - How to confirm password entry with ENTER only and not a click/loss of focus

Tags: unity, input

I have an input field password box, currently the password is 'submitted' either by clicking Enter or by clicking elsewhere on the screen.
This seems to be the designed way, as it states this in the documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-InputField.html) -

*"A UnityEvent that is invoked when the user finishes editing the text content either by submitting or by clicking somewhere that removes the focus from the Input Field."*

As I have other buttons on the same screen that users can click on, I would like it so mouse clicks are not counted as an invoke.

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using an Input event to check when the key pressed, and then manually checking the input field? Something such as: if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Enter)){ }?

Comment: That part of the input field is not really for submitting the data. It's for checking whether the data is in the form you want. You shouldn't use that part and instead write the code @GMR516 suggested in another script and do the password checking process there.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this method to check if the password is correct every time a new character is entered into the text field

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChange.html

You may want to add some checks before seeing if it is correct, like only checking once password is over minimum length so that you don't send unnecessary requests to the login server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I don't want the password to invoke as soon as the password has been typed correctly, what I would like is for it to only do so when ENTER is pressed. The reason being that I have a 'Show Password' toggle button, if the user selects this toggle while typing the password, it counts it as an incorrect password attempt (if it is incomplete) which looks messy.

Comment: Just check for when Enter is input as a value?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CustomSubmit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button SomeButton;
    public InputField Field;
    private bool wasFocused;

    private void Awake()
    {
        SomeButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
            Submit(Field.text);
        });
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (wasFocused && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)) {
            Submit(Field.text);
        }

        wasFocused = Field.isFocused;
    }

    private void Submit(string text)
    {
        Debug.Log("Submit=" + text);
    }
}
```

Comment: "As I have other buttons on the same screen that users can click on, I would like it so mouse clicks are not counted as an invoke." - please describe in more detail, because I faced the same onEndEdit issue, and this simple solution works well with other buttons.

Comment: It's a pity that onEndEdit designed in such [a strange way](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/f0c70f707cf09f959ad417049cb070f8e296ffe2/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/InputField.cs?at=5.5&fileviewer=file-view-default#InputField.cs-2156), and there is no option to change its behaviour.

Comment: It's not an issue at all :)

`SomeButton.onClick = new Button.ButtonClickedEvent();
 SomeButton.onClick.AddListener(() => {
 Submit(Field.text);
});`

Comment: It was just a proof of concept, how one can write custom "Submit", that react to ENTER only and not a click/loss of focus. Other buttons can be simply added to this scenario if required.

Comment: I edited the answer to illustrate what I mean (added a button example).

Comment: Did you manage to implement your custom confirm password entry? If you have some constructive suggestions/questions - feel free to write them. Because "it didn't really work" isn't helpful to anyone.

Comment: Good luck :)
p.s. If one doesn't want to understand the essence of things, then nobody can help in this.

Comment: And there is no need to delete your own comments)

Comment: It is perfectly fine to delete ones comments if I find they are obsolete (as such, you can actually flag comments to be removed for being obsolete). *I do not wish to have further discussion with you*, please stop flagging me in your comments.